# next@14.0.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18.17.0". Got "18.16.0"

Tags: node.js, npm, yarn-v2

I'm trying to create nextjs-app. But when I've tried to install it. This error below is occuring:

[image]

I've tried to run `yarn cache clean`.
I've tried to update `node`.

[image]

Also I've tried to put

```js
"engines": {
  "node": "18.16.0"
}
```

in the `package.json`

Comment: Have you tried using a Node version that _is_ compatible?

Answer (score 3):

`create-next-app` seems to require Node.js 18.17.0 or higher. Upgrade your Node.js version and you should be good to go.

Comment: please check the question again

Comment: @OsamaMohammed Hm, I think _you_ should check your own question again. The screenshot you showed (which by the way should not be a screenshot! never post screenshots of text!) tells you that you have 18.16.0 but it requires 18.17.0 or higher. 16 is clearly smaller than 17. (It doesn't matter that you specified that your _own_ package needs 18.16.0, that won't change what `create-next-app` requires.) Installing a _local_ `node` binary using [the `node` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) that you used also won't change that, it's only used for scripts within your package.json.